# Does root tag have attributes in XML

Tags: xml

This is a sample xml I am trying to create and could not find any documentation on root tag.
But every xml document should have a root tag is all I know.

```
  <payroll  month="JAN2021">  
      <emp ID="123">
         <name>xyz</name>
         <age>50</age>
      </emp>
    </payroll>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can say that your XML is ***well-formed***: It follows the syntactical rules for being XML.

You are right that every XML document must have a root element.  In fact, it must have *exactly one* root element.  This is one of the rules for an XML document to be well-formed.

The root element, like all elements in XML, may have attributes.

There is an additional level of rules that may be specified by a schema (such as XSD, DTD, Relax NG, etc): These user-defined rules specify a vocabulary and grammar for the elements and attributes, how these components may be arranged, and what their values may be.  These rules define whether an XML document is ***valid***.

In summary regarding your example:

1. It is *well-formed* XML.
2. It may be *valid* XML.  We would have to associate a schema with it to be able to say.
3. Without a schema, any attributes could be added to any element.
4. With a schema, the names, values, and placement of attributes would be limited to constraints specified in the schema.

**See also:** [Is there any difference between 'valid xml' and 'well formed xml'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134494/290085)

Comment: Thanks much. Well explained.